In WPF, how can I add a button to each tree view node that is expandable?
The node may be expanded or collapsed. Need to show the button in both cases.
Something like this:
├─ item1
├─ item2 <button>
│  ├─ item2-1
│  ├─ item2-2
├─ item3 <button>
│  ├─ item3-1
│  ├─ item3-2
├─ item4
├─ item5

Best to do it in the XAML.
Thanks for ideas.

In order to do that, you need to start off by copying source XAML for tree view items, which can be found here, in Microsoft docs.
Then you can analyze the code and see part which uses HasItems property to adjust visual of the control. Starting from there, you will see one control named PART_Header that is handled by triggers:
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false" />
        <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
</MultiTrigger>

So, we can add another control (button) next to the element with name PART_Header, like below
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <ContentPresenter
         x:Name="PART_Header"
         HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
         ContentSource="Header" />
     <Button x:Name="PART_Header_Button" Content="Expand" />
 </StackPanel>

and adjust the trigger to also handle our button:
<Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Header_Button" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</MultiTrigger>

